# Changing the return type of a method based on the type of objects in the list

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I want to refactor my code from non-typed objects to typed objects.

For example, here is my current code:

```
public class TestClass {

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    public ArrayList testMethodA() {
        list.add("string1");
        list.add("string2");
        list.add("string3");
        list.add("string4");
        list.add("string5");
        return list;
    }
}
```

I want to turn this into a typed List, so it becomes

```
public class TestClass {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<String> testMethodA() {
        list.add("string1");
        list.add("string2");
        list.add("string3");
        list.add("string4");
        list.add("string5");
        return list;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to change the return type from `ArrayList` to `ArrayList<Object>` based on the type of `obj1`, `obj2`, ...]?  For example, if what's being added to the list are of type `String`, then is it possible to change the return value from `ArrayList` to `ArrayList<String>` dynamically?

I'm using Eclipse, so if there is a plugin (or script or something) that can help me do this it would be much appreciated.

If there is no 'automatic' way of doing this it would mean 5-6 days of manual fixing, which I would rather avoid.

Comment: 3 things. 1 Always code to *the interface*. 2. Always use *generics*. 3. You don't have to return `list` if it can be accessed by other methods directly.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case I have a huge code base in which i have to change the return types by going through each class and check what is being added and change it manually, i don't have the permission to change the code. I don't want to do this thing manually, so I'm trying to use any available ***plugin*** or write a script which achieves the following task.

Comment: @Srikar It doesn't really say in your question, but are you actually refactoring your code from non-typed objects to typed objects? From the question it looks like you have the code just like you want it and you want to change the non-typed->typed at runtime.

Comment: @Chewtoy Actually the code i posted is just a really small example, actually in the code base which i have, i have to change all the non-typed return types to typed-object return type, based on the object type of a  particular collection, may it be a list or map or any other collection. Eclipse gives you an option to change the return type ***(Alt+Shift+C)***, but there you have to manually type for each method, I want to achieve it programatically.

Comment: The short answer would be, "Why are you doing this?  Just go through with the refactor at a slower and less error-prone pace," and the long answer would involve some convoluted code with generics.  You say that you have to change all of your raw types around?  About how many do you estimate there are?

Comment: @Makoto There are 1000's are there, and it may take a 5-6 days to refactor them all manually.

Comment: @Srikar:  That'd probably be 5-6 days well spent as opposed to trying to shim anything else in.  Personal opinion, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the java editor: *Right-click* > *Refactor* > *Infer Generic Type Arguments...*

Have a look at the documentation of Eclipse's "Infer Generic Type Arguments" refactoring: http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-menu-refactor.htm

Also see this previous stackoverflow question: [How to use "Infer Generic Type Arguments..." in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641725/how-to-use-infer-generic-type-arguments-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is exactly what you want, but you can do it with generics:

```
public static List<T> testMethodA(T... objs) {
    return Arrays.stream(objs).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

You will only be able to have one type in a single List, which will be determined by the type of the objects passed in.  If you specifically want a class to contain this list, you can try:

```
public class TestClass<T> {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<T> testMethodA(T... obj)
    ...
}
```

You will not be able to change the type after you create the instance of the object though.  However, each instance can have a different type.

Comment: I have a codebase, I cannot change it. Unfortunately they have not made the methods generic.

Comment: For a clearer understanding of my problem refer to the comment i wrote to @Chewtoy

Comment: In that case, what assumptions can you make.  Are you guaranteed all objects in the list are the same type?  What are the possible types that can be in the list.  Is it some finite set of types, or unknown?

Comment: By far i have been able to get what type of objects are there in the collection, i have to add that object to the return type of the method.

Comment: You cannot change the return type without changing the method, but you can cast the returned object after you get it.

Comment: eclipse has an option to change the return type of the method, using infer generic type arguments, i want to do that in all the classes programmatically, not manually

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use generics for that.

```
 public  <T> List<T> someGenericListMethod(T[] objs){

    List<T> lObj = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(int i=0; i<objs.length;++i)
        lObj.add(objs[i]);

    return lObj;
}
```

Comment: Please refer to the comment i wrote to @Chewoy for a clearer understanding of my problem.

Comment: If you declare your list as List<Object> you'll be able to store any type in it. It's then up to the calling methods to do the appropriate casts.